# Making another module importable from my Python module

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I have a Python module directory structure like this:

```
my_module
|--__init__.py
|--public_interface
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--my_sub_module
|  |  |--__init__.py
|  |  |--code.py
|  |--some_more_code.py
|--other directories omitted
```

Now, the `public_interface` directory (among several others) is only there to organize the code into logical sub-units, as a guideline for me and other developers. The eventual user of `my_module` shall only see it as `my_module.my_sub_module` without the `public_interface` in-between.

I wrote these `__init__.py` files:

> `my_module.__init__.py`:
>
> ```py
> from .public_interface import *
> ```

and

> `my_module.public_interface.__init__.py`:
>
> ```py
> from . import my_sub_module
> from .some_more_code import *
> ```

and

> `my_module.public_interface.my_sub_module.__init__.py`:
>
> ```py
> from .code import *
> ```

This works fine as long as the user imports only the top-level module:

```py
import my_module

my_module.my_sub_module.whatever  # Works as intended
```

However, this does not work:

```py
from my_module import my_sub_module
```

nor:

```py
import my_module.my_sub_module
```

What would I have to change to make these last two imports work?

Comment: Just OOC, why is the public interface the buried one, rather than the private interface?

Comment: This is more like an example, to get the point across what I want to achieve and why. The actual directory names are different but make sense for me and the other developers regarding both, the public interface and the business logic. I would only change it if I absolutely have to in order to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import system only allows actual packages and modules to be imported directly as part of the dotted module name, but your:

```
from .public_interface import *
```

hack just makes `my_sub_module` an attribute of the `my_module` package, not an actual submodule for the purposes of the import system. It breaks for the same reason doing:

```
from collections._sys import *
```

breaks; yes, as an implementation detail, the `collections` package happens to import `sys` aliased to `_sys`, but that doesn't actually make `_sys` a subpackage of `collections`, it's just one of many attributes on the `collections` package. From the import machinery's point of view, `my_sub_module` is no more a submodule of `my_module` than `_sys` is of `collections`; the fact that nested in a sub-directory under `my_module` is irrelevant.

That said, the import system provides a hook to allow you to treat additional arbitrary directories as being part of package, [the `__path__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#module-path). By default, `__path__` just includes the path to the package itself (so `my_module`'s `__path__` defaults to `['/absolute/path/to/my_module']`), but you can programmatically manipulate it however you want; when resolving submodules, it will search only through the final contents of `__path__`, much like importing top level modules searches `sys.path`. So to resolve your particular case (wanting all packages/modules in `public_interface` to be importable without specifying `public_interface` in the import line), just change your `my_module/__init__.py` file to have the following contents:

```
import os.path
__path__.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'public_interface'))
```

All that does is tell the import system that, when `import mymodule.XXXX` occurs (`XXXX` is a placeholder for a real name), if it can't find `my_module/XXXX` or `my_module/XXXX.py`, it should look for `my_module/public_interface/XXXX` or `my_module/public_interface/XXXX.py`. If you want it to search `public_interface` first, change it to:

```
__path__.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'public_interface'))
```

or to have it *only* check `public_interface` (so nothing directly under `my_module` is importable at all), use:

```
__path__[:] = [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'public_interface')]
```

to replace the contents of `__path__` entirely.

---

Side-note: You might wonder why `os.path` is an exception to this rule; on CPython, `os` is a plain module with an attribute `path` (which happens to be the module `posixpath` or `ntpath` depending on platform), yet you can do `import os.path`. This works because the `os` module, while being imported, explicitly (and hackily) populates the `sys.modules` cache for `os.path`. This isn't normal, and it has a performance cost; `import os` must *always* import `os.path` implicitly, even if nothing from `os.path` is ever used. `__path__` avoids that problem; nothing is imported unless requested.

You *could* achieve the same result by making `my_module/__init__.py` contain:

```
import sys
from .public_interface import my_sub_module

sys.modules['my_module.my_sub_module'] = my_sub_module
```

which would allow people to use `my_module.my_submodule` having only done `import my_module`, but that would *force* any `import` of `my_module` to import `public_interface` and `my_sub_module`, even if nothing from `my_sub_module` is ever used. `os.path` continues to do it for historical reasons (using `os.path` APIs with only `import os` a long time ago, and a lot of code relies on that misbehavior because programmers are lazy and it worked), but new code shouldn't use this hack.